# Partition of unity for analytic manifolds over non-Archimedean local fields

Tags: p-adic-analysis, p-adic-groups, non-archimedean-fields, p-adic, p-adic-integration

I am looking for a reference to the following fact which, I hope, is correct.

Let $X$ be a compact analytic manifold over a non-Archimedean local field. Let
$X=\cup_\alpha U_\alpha$ be a finite open covering. Then there exist continuous (or even better, locally constant) functions
$$\phi_\alpha\colon X\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$$

such that $supp(\phi_\alpha)\subset U_\alpha$ and $\sum_{\alpha}\phi_\alpha=1$.

If there is a generalization to non-compact manifolds I will be happy to have a reference.

Comment: You get a continuous partition of unity under very general conditions, see https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~crain101/topologie11/chapter5.pdf. To make it locally constant, use convolution.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by analytic manifold over a non-Archimedean local field? Do you have a specific theory in mind?

Answer (score 6):

It follows from Lemma 1 (part (2)) on page 7 in [http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/Bernst_Lecture_p-adic_repr.pdf](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Ebernstei/Publication_list/publication_texts/Bernst_Lecture_p-adic_repr.pdf)

In the non-compact case, I think that you need to ask the l-space to be countable at infinity. In this case, you can replace your cover with a clopen countable cover, then subtract all the previous open sets from the cover from each $U_\alpha$. In this way, you get a clopen disjoint refinement of your cover. The characteristic functions of the clopen sets of the refinement will give the partition of unity

Comment: Thank you. At the link the relevant lemma is not proven. This is helpful, but more complete treatment is desirable.